# Trouble installing 12.0.4 into Virtual Box

Tags: 12.04, installation, virtualbox

Install into Virtual Box seems to go along OK until the final screen - the restart occurs and a cli message tells me to "Please remove installation media and close tray (if any) then press ENTER"

Regardless of the install being an iso image on the host system or an actual disk the system will not restart, the enter cmd doesn't seem to work.

How do I get this VM to restart ??

Answer (score 0):

In VirtualBox, click on Machine, and then choose Reset, and that will restart the machine for you.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work, everything is lost from memory, so no OS to boot to  :-(

Comment: Does it display any error messages?

Comment: Just that mentioned above

Comment: No, I mean when you click on Reset, what happens after that?

Comment: Nothing, get a failure to load OS type message from Vbox

Comment: What OS do you have as Host? And are you installing 32bit or 64bit Ubuntu?

Comment: Running VB on Mac OSX, all on 32bit. Just tried to reload again, loaded telling me that it's in low graphics mode, offers to run in this mode and goes to a cli to log in. I can log in but nothing beyond this ?

Comment: .... I've also installed XP and Suse with no issues, just Ubuntu seems to be playing up ?

Comment: Take a look at [How to Install & Run Ubuntu Linux in VirtualBox](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/27/install-run-ubuntu-linux-virtualbox/).

Comment: Not a problem :).  Let  me know if it works.

Comment: Tried with 64 bit - all works fine now - for some reason :-)

Comment: Good.  Glad that it works. :)